# Laravel 5.6: Call to a member function getRealPath() on string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send an email with a file in my project in Laravel, but I am getting this error `Call to a member function getRealPath() on string`
This is my `store` function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{     
    $data = array(
       'destino'    => $request['destino'],
       'asunto'     => $request['asunto'],
       'contenido'  => $request['contenido'],
       'a_file'     => $request['a_file']
    );

    Mail::send('administracion.email.email_body', $data, function($message) use ($data)
    {

        $message->to($data['destino']);
        $message->subject($data['asunto']);
        $message->from(Config::get('mail.username'));

        $message->attach($data['a_file']->getRealPath(), array(
        'as'    => 'a_file' . $data['a_file']->getClientOriginalExtension(),
        'mime'  => $data['a_file']->getMimeType()) 
        );
    });

    return Redirect::to('email');

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `$request['a_file']` is giving you a string, instead of an `UploadedFile` instance. Does your form support file uploads?

The way to add this using the laravelcollective Form facade is by passing `'files' => true` in the options like this:

`{!! Form::open(['url' => route('myRoute'), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) !!}`

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#file-input

Or if you're not using the Form helper, set the `enctype` html attribute like this:

`<form method="POST" action="http://example.com" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>`

Comment: I just add the enctype and it worked fine just for one thing. I am getting this file name: a_datatxt 
I mean, without a point between the name file and the extension

Comment: You're concatenating without the `.` between `a_file` and the extension:

`'as'    => 'a_file' . $data['a_file']->getClientOriginalExtension()`

the above should be something like this, note the dot after `a_file`:

`'as'    => 'a_file.' . $data['a_file']->getClientOriginalExtension()`